# JS/TS: Error with 2D Array of strings suddenly becoming undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, multidimensional-array, undefined-behavior

I'm making a Connect 4 game for a Discord.js application. I'm keeping the game board as a 2D array of strings and initializing it like so:

```
var board:string[][] = new Array<Array<string>>();
```

```
function resetBoard():void {
  for(let i=0; i<numRows; i++){
    board[i] = new Array<string>();
    for(let j=0; j<cols; j++){
      board[i].push(" ");
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I try to access a part of the board, it throws an error "cannot read property '0' of undefined".

```
function whatsAtPos(row, col){
  return board[row][col];
}
```

All of the functions are in the same file, and the board[][] is a global variable. I've tried everything up my sleeve to fix it and I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: It seems like your either your `board` or `board[row]` is undefined. Maybe somewhere in your code you are messing with `board` ? :D

Comment: ... or, somewhere in your code, you might accidentally call `whatsAtPos(x, 0)`, where `x` is greater than `numRows - 1` (removing `1` because indexes start at `0`). If you can't use a debugger, you can still use `console.log` to understand what's happening.

Comment: It is mostly the issue in whatsAtPos method

Comment: Bdw instead of using a multidimensional array, i preffer using a flat array. Let's say you want to get 2,3 from your multi array what you do is `arr[2][3]`, in flat array you can just do, arr[2 * 3 + 1], it's gonna give you same object. It's just a preferance obv.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to:

- verify you called resetBoard() before you called whatsAtPos
- validate that while reseting board 'numRows', 'cols' that you used will be const or not change before calling
- add validation:
  to function `whatsAtPos` arguments about types , and during the function validate value of row, col that will be in range of [0, numRows-1], [0, cols-1]